# Index of "string" in array returns -1 always, using "Arrays.asList"

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the index for a "string" from the array, and I am always getting "-1". Case below:

```
String[] sDrawerOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DrawerOptions);
int pos = (Arrays.asList(R.array.DrawerOptions).indexOf(R.string.ta_notification));
//pos = -1 (always)
```

The resource content is as:

```
<string name="ta_notification">Notifications</string>
<string-array name="DrawerOptions">
    <item>@string/ta_notification</item>
</string-array>
```

Do you see any bug, help me out in understanding.

Answer (score 2):

`R.string` are int values not String. Change it to

```
indexOf(getString(R.string.ta_notification)));
```

or

```
indexOf(getResources().getString(R.string.ta_notification)));
```

to retrieve the String referenced by the id.

Also change

`Arrays.asList(R.array.DrawerOptions)`

to

```
Arrays.asList(sDrawerOptions)
```

thanks to [@pathfindereilte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/666884/pathfinderelite)

Comment: `Arrays.asList(R.array.DrawerOptions)` is also bad